# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object error for date range in Django

Tags: django, datetime, filter

I am trying to filter `CartItem` objects based on their delivery dates. I define a `startfilterdate` and an `endfilterdate` that i format as a string in the same way my delivery_date's are formatted. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

**models.py**

```
class CartItems(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='restaurant', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delivery_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class RestaurantOrders(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RestaurantOrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        restaurant_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        startfilterdate = date.today()
        startfilterdate = startfilterdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        endfilterdate = date.today()+timedelta(days=9)
        endfilterdate = endfilterdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        orders = CartItems.objects.filter(restaurant_id = restaurant_id, delivery_date=[startfilterdate,endfilterdate])
```

Error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`range`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup as,

```
orders = CartItems.objects.filter(..., delivery_date__range=[startfilterdate,endfilterdate])
```

Comment: ahhhh i see, now all the other answers i read make sense, didnt understand the syntax, thanks!